# Google Chrome won't load two CSS files

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rendering, google-chrome-devtools

I just started creating a personal website for me, then I came across a problem. As soon as I include two stylesheets, the second stylesheet doesn't load (doesn't render). My **first stylesheet** that does load (does render) looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'archive';
    src: url('archive-webfont.eot');
    src: url('archive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('archive-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('archive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('archive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('archive-webfont.svg#archive') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The **second stylesheet** that doesn't load (doesn't render) looks like this:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #333333;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: archive;
}
```

My **HTML** looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Jacques Marais</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/archive.css" title="Archive Font CSS" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" title="Master CSS" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><span class="first-character">J</span>acques Marais</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I look at the `Resources` panel in the Developer Tools, it shows both stylesheets, but when I look at the `Sources` panel, it only shows that one loaded:

**Sources**

[image: Sources Panel]

**Resources**

[image: Resources Panel]

I tried all methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630010/chrome-not-loading-stylesheet) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867746/css-not-working-in-chrome).

**Update**

Here are the `Network` and `Console` panes.

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

[image]

**Update 3**

[image]

Comment: do these stylesheets have any `@import`s ?

Comment: @Trix Nope, none. The stylesheets I included in the question contains all code that I used.

Comment: any lines starting with `@`, although I can see one, the font-face. any others?

Comment: would u please provide screenshot of network and console tabs?

Comment: Plase Audit the present state, using the Audit tab and let me see the results

Comment: Have you checked whether the DOM really contains the link tag? Whatever this inject.js does it might have removed it for whatever reason

Comment: @Aurus It does, I added an image to show that it does.

Comment: u may debug ur webpage loading experience using Chrome Inspector. while open, press `Ctrl + P` to start the debugger

Comment: @Trix `Ctrl + P` opens the Sources panel to search for a file.

Comment: Please upload ur page somewhere and provide the link

Comment: @Trix http://jacquesmarais.github.io/34462706/

Comment: @Trix Thanks for all your help. It seems like the `title` attributes were causing the problem.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to look up the CSS `::first-letter` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Jacques Marais</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/archive.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><span class="first-character">J</span>acques Marais</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just deleted the title attribute inside your link tag and it works. (I've tested it on my webserver)

No title attribute inside `<link>` tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

**Ops**, never mind, it supports global attribute (included title), anyway if you delete them the page works... I've noticed also it works if you leave title attributes but without spaces inside them. 
Try to change your titles and delete all the spaces.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure is it really work or not. I have faced this same problem and found solution. At the second stylesheet do like this -

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'archive'; /* add your font-family name inside '' */ 
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Thank you for the suggestion though.