# HTML <select> with background-color <option> tags using Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-select

I'm trying to make a drop down list that allows a user to select from a list of colors. I want the background of each `<option>` item to be the color that the user can choose. As proof of concept, I made this little html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        .white  {background-color:white;}
        .red    {background-color:red;}
        .yellow {background-color:yellow;}
        .green  {background-color:green;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Choose Color</h2>
    <select>
        <option class="white">This should have a WHITE background</option>
        <option class="red">This should have a RED background</option>
        <option class="yellow">This should have a YELLOW background</option>
        <option class="green">This should have a GREEN background</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run this on Firefox, either on a PC or a Mac, it looks great. However, testing it on Chrome on a Mac, it doesn't show these background colors. Here is a screen shot of the page after it renders in Chrome and I click on the `select` object:

[image]

You can see that the list is just in the standard format with gray backgrounds. You can also see that the items are connected with the correct class.

I am aware that there are a few [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521565/html-select-with-different-background-color-for-every-option-that-works-properly) on this issue, which is where I got my initial code from. However, none of the posts that I read on this issue are working for me.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521565/html-select-with-different-background-color-for-every-option-that-works-properly)

Comment: Could not get the point in each option color should be visible am i right?

Comment: @David784 - that is the exact post that I linked to. I tried this, but it is not working for me.

Comment: your code is work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/zacvybc5/

Comment: @NifrasIsmail - Yes, that is the point. I want it to look a little bit like a rainbow. Each row in the drop down has its own background color based on the class to which it is assigned.

Comment: @NifrasIsmail -  what browser are you using. Your JSFiddle is not working for me, either. I am using Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: I'm also using chrome. It should be work

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see from my screen shot, it is not working for me. Weird...

Comment: I do nothing just copy and paste your code. It working fine. check it in another browser like firefox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107423/discussion-between-nifras-ismail-and-randall).

Comment: It is not possible as far as I know to style Option elements - you can style the whole Select element to a certain degree, but the issue is that most Form elements like Select are widgets provided by the browser rather than standard HTML elements - thus they vary depending  on the browser in appearance and ability to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling option has some problem on different OS. Are you not allowed to use any plugin like [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select)? Since the element is li, this will surely accomplish what you want

Comment: I should be able to use that plugin. Would you mind giving me a quick idea as to how to use it to style the select object? Good suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Just add the script above and what you want  to achieve is on their docs http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#style-individual-options

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. However, I STILL have the same issue - it works on Firefox but not on Chrome.

Comment: Do you mean it's not wroking on chrome even by using bootstrap-select plugin? That's weird because it's working on my end. Chrome with Mac OS.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Would you mind posting your code, particularly the header links? That could be my issue. I've used the exact code from Silvio Moreto's site, but still no love. Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out, more or less. I wasn't importing all of the links that I needed. I have the colors figured out, so now I just need to tweak things a bit. Thanks for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, the answer given was using JavaScript and some CSS manipulation, this is working fine on my end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        .white  {background-color:white;color:red;}
        .red    {background-color:red;color:black;}
        .yellow {background-color:yellow;color:black;}
        .green  {background-color:green;color:white;}
    </style>


</head>
<body>

    <h2>Choose Color</h2>
    <select>
        <option class="white">This should have a WHITE background</option>
        <option class="red">This should have a RED background</option>
        <option class="yellow">This should have a YELLOW background</option>
        <option class="green">This should have a GREEN background</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        var select = document.querySelector('select');
        var colorChange = function(){
            var color = select.options[select.selectedIndex].className;
            select.className = color;
            select.blur();
        };
        select.addEventListener('change', colorChange);
        colorChange();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also I added the `color` property in a couple classes to show you can manipulate more than just the background color.

Comment: Thank you. What browser / os are you using? I've discovered that it works correctly in Firefox on a PC, but not in Chrome on a Mac. I've edited my post to focus the issue on that browser.

Comment: I tested it on Chrome, FF, and IE but I am using Windows.

Comment: @faino - this is impressive - I've not seen it before. Is it solely HTML 5? - I'm stuck with 4...

Comment: @TonyDuffill - there are posts on doing this going all the way back to 2004, so it should be able to be done pre-HTML5. Try it out (just not on Chrome for Mac!).

Comment: @Randall - thanks, yes, I've tried it - bizarrely this has passed me by for all these years - I was always told option elements weren't style-able.

Answer (score 0):

@Randal Here you can check your code is working fine. Run code snippet on the bottom

```css
<head>

    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        .white  {background-color:white;}
        .red    {background-color:red;}
        .yellow {background-color:yellow;}
        .green  {background-color:green;}
    </style>
```

```html
<body>

    <h2>Choose Color</h2>
    <select>
        <option class="white">This should have a WHITE background</option>
        <option class="red">This should have a RED background</option>
        <option class="yellow">This should have a YELLOW background</option>
        <option class="green">This should have a GREEN background</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you. When I run your code snippet, it does not work for me. It must be something about Chrome / OSX, right?

Comment: Now check on your browser chrome on Mac. It should be work

Comment: Oops. okay it may be.

Comment: Yes @Randall It's a big issue on behind. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630010/chrome-not-loading-stylesheet