# How to set background-color for <select> and avoid styling in the <option>'s dropdown

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to style a `<select>` elements `background-color` on `:hover` and at the same time leave the styling of the `<option>` dropdown untouched. It seems to me that this issue occurs only in Firefox and not in Chrome/Safari.

[Chrome select with background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNci6.png)

[Firefox select with background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBtS6.png)

This would be the code snippet. Please notice that I don't want to have the dropdown to be affected by the background-color in Firefox. Also: Not only the background color changes. Also the borders change. The whole "native" look gets lost as soon as I give the select a background-color.

```css
select {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<select><option>Option</option></select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is mentioned before:<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239356/html-select-with-background-color-option-tags-using-chrome<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color

Comment: but they are talking about styling <option> there. I don't want to style it. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Why not to try to set the properties of the options in select too, something like:

```
select option{
background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This is not suitable for my case for two reasons:
1. The design system I'm working on has a color scheme where we depend on transparent backgrounds of elements that get different opacity-layers (on hover etc.) those opacity layers then mix with the background and result in a color.

2. I really want to leave the styling of the options to the browsers/os

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a proper workaround.

We need to apply the hover color to a parent div and use `:focus-within`.

```css
div:focus-within {
background: red;
}

select {
background: transparent;
border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><select><option>Option</option></select></div>
```